# WebRTC local signaling server

Tags: android, webrtc, p2p, signaling

I am trying to figure out a solution for a signaling server for an Android WebRTC based project.  Both clients will be Android and both located close to each other, i.e. - within 100 yards or less.  I would like the solution to work without the use of a public signaling server.  I would rather just have one of the clients also act as the server.

So, my question is :
1.  How can I achieve it so that one is the server?  i.e. - Can I set one as a hotspot or use wifi direct?
2.  If I can achieve #1, then what is a good solution for a signaling server running on android ?  Can I run one of the nodejs servers on android ?

Comment: Do you want to call without Internet?

Comment: @Haven - yes.  I do not need to go over the net.

Answer (score 4):

A signaling server is simply a way to exchange messages between two parties. In the WebRTC case these messages are the offer/answer and ICE candidates.

You can use whatever type of server you want to do this, you can even do it manually :).

You can use one of the clients as the server too, but then you will have to communicate the IP to the other somehow. Maybe use Wi-Fi direct and get it programatically.

Comment: Thanks Adrian.  So, are you saying I do not even need a server in this scenario?  I.e. - could i just use webrtc with straight web sockets over a local hotspot ?  That way keeping the process within my app ?

Comment: Since I know the IP address of the clients, I don't need traverse the NATs.  So wondering if i can do without the need for TURN, STUN and ICE candidates.

Comment: You do need a server, because you need somehow to transfer the messages automatically. But the server and the client can be in the same app.

Comment: You don't need a STUN/TURN server, but you do need the ICE process.

Answer (score 3):

With WebRTC, signaling server is just the way to help you transfer your message, exchange your information (SDP package(createOffer/answer), exchange candidates etc).

Example : You can use GCM (Free) as a signaling server, or using Nodejs with socket.io, websocket, XMPP etc. Only thing you need is transfer your message between two peers.

You can refer to this tutorial : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Comment: Thanks @Khoatd, I understand the purpose of the signaling.  My question is more in terms of what is a good mechanism to perform the signaling in my scenario - 2 android clients w/ no internet connection,  assuming one acts as a server.